# GLKit + Cocos2d 2.0?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, glkit

I am trying to use the [GLKBaseEffect](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKBaseEffect_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) (from GLKit) to create a light effect on a CCSprite inside my game based on Cocos2D 2.0.

I read a lot of threads and articles and unfortunately GLKit and Cocos2D 2.0 are never used together.

Could someone please just show me the direction to integrate a simple GLKBaseEffect (e.g. the light effect) on a CCSprite of Cocos2D 2.0?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GLKit and Cocos2D are never used together because they're both OpenGL wrappers. You can't combine, mix or share them or their functionality. Each uses their own OpenGL context.

If you want particle effects in cocos2d, you'll have to use a Particle Design tool or write shaders for more elaborate effects.